# Calculate time ago / days ago from javascript dates that had to be converted to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Due to limitations with next js, data could not be passed to client without being converted to string.

So date obtaned from database is is now a string:

```
 Past date as string is:   20200802016944990
```

I use new Date() to get the current date and convert it to string as well (Notice T is missing from my string date)

```
Present date as string is: 20200805013945088
```

In both cases, I the code below to convert to string

```
.toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

If these were not strings, its simple as date1 - date 2.

How to get mins/ hours/ days ago from past date and present date which are now strings?

I am using React js and Next js. I do not want to install a library like moment js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is instead convert it to ISOstring, would be convert it to milliseconds with getTime() (it returns a number), and then would be easir to recover date and get the info you want (day, hours, minutes, etc..)

```js
const dbDate = new Date().getTime();

console.log('getTime value =>', dbDate);

const parsedDate = new Date(dbDate);

console.log('parsed date =>', parsedDate);

console.log('Date =>', parsedDate .getDate());
console.log('Hours =>', parsedDate .getHours());
console.log('Minutes =>', parsedDate .getMinutes());

//Once you get the dates, you can do the date calculate, like:

//Get 1 day in milliseconds
var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

const date1 = new Date('9/9/2020').getTime(); //JUST AN EXAMPLE
const date2 = new Date('10/9/2020').getTime(); //JUST AN EXAMPLE

const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);

const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / one_day); 

console.log(diffTime + " milliseconds");
console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

Comment: This works to get the date from server to client. How to get difference though? does `newDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime()` give the difference in milliseconds? I am trying this out.

Comment: Hi @FKM. Exactly, you do this newDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime(), but to get the difference in days, just need to do another calc... i update the answer with it.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would suggest keeping the original Date - or the unedited ISO string, you can parse the value (since it is an ISO String, all data is kept and we can reconstruct the original.

This little function can convert the strings back to `Date`s (note: this uses some ES6 features which are not strictly necessary but can be avoided in exchange for more verbose code)

```js
const s = "20200805013945088";


function parseDate(s) {
  let t = [s.substr(0, 4)];
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    t.push(s.substr(4 + (2 * i), 2))
  }
  t.push(s.substr(14));
  t = t.map((s)=>parseInt(s));
  return new Date(...t);
}

console.log(parseDate(s));
```

Comment: I agree with you so I am keeping it as `.toISOString()`. I get both dates in the format 2020-08-02T20:07:50.865Z but difference is NAN. I have to play with this

Comment: @FKM, you would still need to convert them to `Date`s with `Date(isoString)`